# Editing Font Size/Style of Bokeh Paragraph Widget

Tags: python, pandas, fonts, bokeh

I've been working with Bokeh for the past week, but there's one thing I can't seem to do.

Here's a portion of my script:

```
data5 = dict(depth = df4['Depth'], length = df4['Length'], recovery = df4['Recovery'], peak = df4['Peak'], valley = df4['Valley'], exitdate = df4['Exit Date'])
data6 = dict(returns = df5['Return'], correlation = df5['Correlation'])

source5 = ColumnDataSource(data5)
source6 = ColumnDataSource(data6)

columns5 = [TableColumn(field = 'depth', title = 'Depth'), TableColumn(field = 'length', title = 'Length (Months)'), 
            TableColumn(field = 'recovery', title = 'Recovery (Months)'), TableColumn(field = 'peak', title = 'Peak'),
            TableColumn(field = 'valley', title = 'Valley'), TableColumn(field = 'exitdate', title = 'Exit Date')]
columns6 = [TableColumn(field = 'returns', title = 'Return'), TableColumn(field = 'correlation', title = 'Correlation')]           

table5 = DataTable(source = source5, columns = columns5, width = 700, height = 350, editable = False)
table6 = DataTable(source = source6, columns = columns6, width = 400, height = 300, editable = False)

para5 = Paragraph(text = 'Portfolio', height = 1)
para6 = Paragraph(text = 'Benchmark', height = 1)

title2 = Paragraph(text = 'Drawdown Review (Since Sep 2011)', height = 1)

t2 = vplot(vform(para5), vform(table5)) 
t3 = vplot(vform(para6), vform(table6))
t4 = hplot(t2, t3)
q5 = vplot(vform(title2), t4)

tab0 = Panel(child = q0, title = 'Rolling Statistics')
tab1 = Panel(child = q1, title = 'Up-Down Capture')
tab2 = Panel(child = q2, title = 'Historical Statistics')
tab3 = Panel(child = q3, title = 'Historical Track Record')
tab4 = Panel(child = q4, title = 'Historical Analysis')
tab5 = Panel(child = q5, title = 'Drawdown Review')

tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab3, tab4, tab5, tab0 ,tab1, tab2])
bk.io.show(tabs)
```

I realised there's no way (is there?) to set a title for a page/tab within bokeh for the whole gridplot. So I inserted paragraphs (para5/para6). This works well except the text is in Times New Roman and I'd like it to be another font, say Arial, and for it to be bold and underlined.

I tried things like `title2.text_font_style = 'arial'` but that didn't work.

[According to the documentation](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#paragraph), paragraph doesn't have this sort of attribute.

Is there a roundabout way of setting the font of a paragraph widget?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [`Div`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#div) widget instead:

> **Div**
>
> A widget for displaying text that can support HTML in a  tag:
>
> ...